# How to edit <head> info

Tags: 7, theming

In Drupal 6 the entire page data was stored in `page.tpl.php`. Now, with Drupal 7, only the content that appears in between `<body>` and `</body>`. So how do you edit the *HEAD info*? Is it still stored in a `.tpl.php` file? Where? If not, how do you do it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If the theme you use does not provide the file for the header, it means that Drupal is using the default one, which is now provided by a module called "system". The file is called html.tpl.php

Just copy this file into your theme, and edit it.

Answer (score 11):

You need to copy default html.tpl.php from system module directory.

Or you can using function `drupal_add_html_head` to override or add new head tag.

```
// First, we must set up an array
$element = array(
  '#tag' => 'link', // The #tag is the html tag - <link />
  '#attributes' => array( // Set up an array of attributes inside the tag
    'href' => 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cardo&subset=latin',
    'rel' => 'stylesheet',
    'type' => 'text/css',
  ),
);
drupal_add_html_head($element, 'google_font_cardo');
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change the head tag, you will need to use [html.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--html.tpl.php/7)

Answer (score 0):

Copying html.tpl.php to your custom theme from the systems module will solve this issue. If you want to have the / tags in each of your custom .tpl files, you can just have only the following in your html.tpl.php file.

`<?php print $page; ?>`